Get a log of everything GParted does when re-sizing a btrfs filesystem
When I use GParted to do some complicated partition and file system manipulation it gives the option to see the details of what steps it took. But this does not give all the details of what underlying commands GParted used.
Is it possible to get a log or debug type of output from GParted so I can see exactly all the commands it used to do whatever I asked it to do?
The reason is because I want to understand exactly what GParted does to do various manipulations on my btrfs file system AND I want to put these commands in to a script for use elsewhere.
Maybe I could run GParted in a debugger and step through while it is for instance shrinking a filesystem/partition?
The GParted online forum has closed so I don't know where else to ask this?
Flex

As far as I can remember from previous uses, expanding the "Details" section of the progress dialog literally shows you the commands used in each step.
forkstat, extrace, or execsnoop can also be used to log each new process started and each binary executed; strace -f -e execve -s 999 gparted will also work.
Some of the manipulation GParted does is not in terms of commands; it uses libparted to directly edit the partition table, for example.
And in general, GParted does not have any understanding of the filesystems (except maybe for FAT) – it relies on their respective tools to do all manipulation, and I suspect that for btrfs, the only command it will use is btrfs filesystem resize (which does everything else internally).
So the process for expanding a partition would be:

Edit the partition table to increase the 'end' boundary of the partition.
Run btrfs filesystem resize ... to rearrange the filesystem.

(For shrinking it's in the opposite order.)

Thank you. The GParted "Details" section does not show all the commands used in each step. It doesn't list out what commands it used in the "Calibrate" section or how it computed the partition and underlying filesystem dimensions in the "Conclusion" section. The only command it does list is the btrfs resize command. Was really only one btrfs command needed? No need to balance the fs or do anything else it is not mentioning? Would be nice to see a listing of all commands with all parameters necessary to achieve what GParted did.

I have already offered four ways to see all commands that GParted runs. As far as I know it doesn't actually do anything in the "calibrate" section. There is no balancing or anything else necessary because that's (literally) the job of the filesystem's resize command, no matter which filesystem.

GParted has to do something to get that information in the Calibrate section and again in the summary section at the end. The btrfs filesystem resize command does not "balance" there is separate btrfs command for that. Thank you for the strace command. But it doesn't reveal everything about what commands and parameters GParted makes use of. I think the only way to see that is by stepping through locally compiled GParted code with a debugger. A very detailed output would be a great learning tool on partition and file system manipulation.
